# How to replace all Character or value in mvc View Page by Replace?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.number.Replace("_","*"))
```

input:- 12_34
I it give's o/p like this :- 12*34

but i want ***** How could i get this result?

and ALSO  i Want 1***4 ?

Please Help me...

Comment: what output you are expecting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i Want 1***4 ?

A simple extension method would do, as shown below. Please add more validations as per your requirements.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string GetString(this string input)
    {
        var arr = input.ToCharArray();

        for (int i = 1; i < arr.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = '*';
        }

        return new string(arr);
    }
}
```

Can be invoked as -

```
string str = "1wfqEGFE1234562_3453".GetString();
```

Output will be - `1******************3`

Answer (score 1):

This method just generates HTML markup, if you need to replace the content of the textbox typed by the user, you should do that on code behind after the submit or via javascript.